# Postman request PUT with body -->form-data with image req.file undefined why?

Tags: postman, multer, webapi

I have a question about a problem I am encountering on a web api (node ​​js, express and multer)
With Postman.
when I do a POST request with the image file in the body -> form-data in the console.log (req.file), I can see the characteristics of the file BUT when I do a put request with the correct url, when i look in the terminal in the req.file i have undefined.
Why on the POST controller I can see the req.file and in the PUT controller I have undefined ???
in any case i should see my file in the req.file

[image: route POST]
[image: route PUT]

[image: POSTMA request PUT body form-data]